# Can I ask questions about mountaineering in Sports SE Site?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

The question is clear! Can I ask questions about mountaineering in the beta site?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a sport so why not?

That said, specific things related to it might be a better fit on [The Great Outdoors](http://outdoors.stackexchange.com)

Comment: Mountaineering questions would work here or at TGO...perhaps [TGO has expertise in place about this](http://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mountaineering), but we wouldn't discourage it here. For all intents and purposes, let's stick to the competitive aspects of mountaineering to specify the overlap for Sports SE.